# If a vector is orthogonal to a subspace, what is its projection?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $y$ is orthogonal to a subspace spanned by the columns of matrix $A$.

My question is, what is the projection of $y$ onto $A$?

I know that the projection of $y$ onto $A$ is the vector in $A$ such that the distance between that vector and $y$ is minimal.

But I think every vector in $A$ in this case attains same distance.

Hence the projection of $y$ onto $A$ is the set of vectors spanned by $A$.

Is my intuition correct?

Comment: Your question, and both answers given so far, assumes that there is **a** projection of $y$ onto the subspace $S_A$ spanned by the columns of $A$. But consider $\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2}$, and $y = \pmatrix{1\\2}$. The subspace $S_A$ is the $y$-axis, so you might say that "the projection" of $y$ is $\pmatrix{0\\2}$. But the transformation represented by $B = \pmatrix{0 &0 \\ 1 & 1}$ is *also* a projection onto $S_A$, and takes $y$ to $\pmatrix{0\\3}$. It just happens to not be an *orthogonal* projection.

Answer (score 1):

The projection of $y$ onto $A$ will be the zero vector. For any other vector $v\in A$ you will have $||y-v|| = \sqrt{||y||^2+||v||^2} > ||y||.$

Answer (score 0):

Zero.

The kernel of the projection onto a subspace $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the subspace, $A^{\perp}$.

That should be your intuition. The zero vector is in a sense the closest vector in $A$ to an orthogonal vector.